# Nested and Associated Enum Values Swift

Tags: swift, enums

One of the best practices endorsed by NSHipster when dealing with tables or collection views is to use an enum to represent each section like so:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SomeSectionType) {
    SomeSectionTypeOne = 0,
    SomeSectionTypeTwo = 1,
    SomeSectionTypeThree = 2
}
```

That makes it really easy to do a switch statement or ifs like:

```
if(indexPath.section == SomeSectionTypeOne) {
    //do something cool
}
```

For sections with static content, I extended the concept to include enums for each item:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SectionOneItemType) {
    ItemTypeOne = 0,
    ItemTypeTwo = 1
}

if(indexPath.section == SomeSectionTypeOne) {
     switch(indexPath.item) {
     case SectionOneItemType:
         //do something equally cool
     default:
     }
}
```

In Swift, I'd like to replicate the same behavior except this time taking advantage of nested enums. I've been able to come up with this so far:

```
enum PageNumber {
    enum PageOne: Int {
        case Help, About, Payment
    }
    enum PageTwo: Int {
        case Age, Status, Job
    }
    enum PageThree: Int {
        case Information
    }
    case One(PageOne)
    case Two(PageTwo)
    case Three(PageThree)
}
```

but I can't see how to go from an `NSIndexPath` and initialize the correct case and then use a switch statement to extract the values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can use nested enum to decide the section and row cell comes from. Because associated values and raw values can't coexist in Swift enumeration. Multiple enums are needed

```
enum sectionType: Int {
    case sectionTypeOne = 0, sectionTypeTwo, sectionTypeThree
}

enum rowTypeInSectionOne: Int {
    case rowTypeOne = 0, rowTypeTwo, rowTypeThree
}

//enum rowTypeInSectionTwo and so on

let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
case (sectionType.sectionTypeOne.rawValue, rowTypeInSectionOne.rowTypeOne.rawValue):
    print("good")
default:
    print("default")
}
```